# How can I combine matching rules in vim into one?

Tags: regex, vim

I have a log file in which I have DEBUG, NORMAL and CRITICAL entries as well as some info that does not start with a regular (for this type of logs) data e.g. `[20130313:123412]`

```
[210313:100114] NORMAL: this is normal log
[210313:100114] DEBUG: ../../common/
Additional info: 
number of ....
```

I would like to remove both `DEBUG` entries as well as those that do not start with `[`

I know I can do that with:

```
:g/DEBUG/d
```

and

```
:g!/^\[/d
```

how can I combine this into one ? Or properly use a regex ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert them both to positive or negative rules (as appropriate), and then you can use `\|` ("or") to match one or the other.

```
:g/^[^\[]\|DEBUG/d
```

That would do it. `^[^\[]` for lines starting with other than `[`, or lines containing `DEBUG`.

Comment: I am waiting until timer (10 min I believe goes off:) )